# How to load local data into js file variable?

Tags: javascript, azure

I am doing an IoT device simulator and I have a dataset of readings that I want to send to the IoT hub. The file I am working on is [here](https://github.com/Azure/device-simulation-dotnet/blob/master/Services/data/devicemodels/scripts/IncreasePressure-method.js). I change it to

```
var data = ???;
data.forEach(function(e){
    state.pressure = e;
    updateState(state);
    log("Pressure increased to " + state.pressure);
    sleep(1000);
})
```

I have a file with all the data I need. Is there any way I can load the data into the file as a variable (var data) of the current js file.

```
function getData() {
var data =
{
    "example": [999,999]
};

return data.example;
}

export function getEventData() {
 getData();
}
```

It give me an error : JS function failure, {"Message":"Line 14: Unexpected reserved word","FullName":"Jint.Parser.ParserException"}

and the 14 line : `import { getEventData } from "./HavenEventData"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different supported languages to upload data into IOT hub, this would also work for the simulation scenario, the current documentation shows .NET, JAVA, Node.js.

> Once you associate an Azure storage account to the IoT Hub, IoT hub generates a SAS URI. A device can use this SAS URI to securely upload a file to a blob container. The IoT Hub service and the device SDKs coordinate the process that generates the SAS URI and makes it available to a device to use to upload a file.

Source is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-file-upload), I'd recommend to check it out since it has examples.

an example of a Method using C# is as follow:

```
private static async void SendToBlobAsync()
{
    string fileName = "image.jpg";
    Console.WriteLine("Uploading file: {0}", fileName);
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    using (var sourceData = new FileStream(@"image.jpg", FileMode.Open))
    {
        await deviceClient.UploadToBlobAsync(fileName, sourceData);
    }

    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time to upload file: {0}ms\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I solved the problem by adding a function in C# and fake it as a js function.

Comment: You're welcome :), when you get a chance, please mark the question as closed since it maybe helpful for future members that are seeking help with the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `var data = require('path_to_you_file')` (but i am assuming its a json file) is it ?

Comment: when i do this it give me an error says there is no such file to be found

Comment: is your path to your file correct ? because it should work

Comment: alternatively you can convert your json file to js and make it look like : 
module.exports = {
  // your_json_data
}
and then just require it again

Comment: I try to import it as a js file but it says:   JS function failure, {"Message":"Line 14: Unexpected reserved word","FullName":"Jint.Parser.ParserException"}

Comment: did you put module.exports first ?
for example it should be like : 
module.exports = {
 fullName: "toto",
 lastname: "tata"
 ...
}

and then you access it doing your require like : 
var data = require('your_file')
data.fullName

Comment: If I do it in your way do i still need to use import?

Comment: yes, import or require because you are exporting something with module.exports, but its really strange that the require / import on your json file doesnt work... it should

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163564/discussion-between-stephenie-liu-and-andre-gomes).

Comment: @StephenieLiu Do you still need help with this issue ?

Adam